# Random image url when reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

What I want is that the URL to some specific images should change on reload / new visit.

No news but this is how it looks today...

```
<li><a href="http://nameToSite/images/bkg1.jpg"></a></li>
```

Is it possible to make a jQuery url change

To something like

```
<li><a href="http://nameToSite/images/randomImages[1].jpg"></a></li> ?
```

thanks, great forum!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will change the link to point to randomImages[1] to randomImages[10] randomly each time it is run.

HTML:

```
<li><a id="link" href="http://nameToSite/images/randomImages[1].jpg"></a></li>
```

JQuery:

```
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1
$("#link").attr('href','http://nameToSite/images/randomImages[' + randomnumber + '].jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use jquery to request the server for an image.  Have a servlet generate a random image URI and respond with it.

Or you could just use simple java script to choose a random image URI from a list onPageLoad.